# php generate word document change page

Tags: php, mysql, ms-word

I'm trying to generate word from php+mysql. I found code to generate it and i have 3 queries. I want to change page in every loop. Is that possible? Now i'm using `<hr>` to separate it. In example i have only 2 big loops, but in my page i have 10 loops and i want 1 loop in 1 page o word. Here's my code

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");

header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename=printorders.doc");

?> 

<?php 
include 'connection.php';
$result = $connection->query('SELECT * FROM main WHERE  (orderid = "100000002" OR orderid = "100000003") GROUP BY orderid ORDER BY orderid'); ?>


<?php   while($row = $result->fetch_array()) { 


    $result3 =  $connection->query("SELECT orderid, BillingStreet, City, Region FROM main WHERE BillingTelephone = '".$row["BillingTelephone"]."' group by orderid ORDER BY  `main`.`orderdate` ASC ");
        while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) { 
            $city =  $row3["City"];
            $region = $row3["Region"];
            $address = $row3["BillingStreet"];
            $idorder = $row3["orderid"];

        }
    ?>
<table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center" id="tbl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>date</th>
            <th>name</th>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $idorder;?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row["insert_date"];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row["CustomerName"];?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>       

<hr style="color: #f00;background-color: #f00;height: 10px;"> <!--here i want to change page-->
<?php 
} 
?>
```

Comment: No, you're generating html markup, and pretending that it's a word document.... simply sending headers to say that the document is a word document doesn't automagically convert it into one

Comment: In order to properly generate Word documents from PHP, you need to use a library like https://phpword.codeplex.com or https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use pagebreak, you can add this line

```
<br style="page-break-before: always">
```